# Database design duplicate column -websafe urls

Tags: php, sql, regex, .htaccess, database-design

In the interest of good relational database design:

There are currently two columns in the DB: "GroupName" and "WebGroupName".  The second column is used for simple url access to a profile. Eg:  www.example.com/myWebGroupName   the reason for this is that it avoids spaces being passed in the url for example:   *www.example.com/my Web Group Name would not work*

To re-iterate the DB structure; column 1 would store "My Group Name" and column two would store "MyGroupName".

Possible solutions may err on the side of storing the group name without spaces then using some regular expression to add the spaces back.  *The focus of my question* is how to eliminate the need for two columns storing near-duplicate date.

Thank you for your time

Comment: I don't really see a problem with having a column specifying the url for a group. But it is hard to understand what your problem is without seeing any code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's in the interest of minimising duplicate data in the database. However, one column is perhaps not worth crying about your right. I was always taught to minimise duplication as much as possible and here it seemed I was failing to do so.

Comment: I wouldn't save the name without spaces. Let's say the company name is "JPMorgan" (a well-known financial services firm): you'd end up saving "JPMorgan" as the "without space" version but when you'll try to reconstitute it, there's no way to know if there was a space between J and P and the between P and Morgan. Instead, if you insist on not saving it, you could use a SQL query that uses string functions such as `REPLACE` to remove spaces from the name and compare it to the value in the URL.

Comment: I may be slow, but what's the problem with spaces in the URL?  Any reasonable browser will encode that before sending, any reasonable application will decode the query parameters before comparing them to the database.  Not to mention that your top-level links are, in most cases, likely to be clicked from an HTML page that you've written anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you really have a problem with spaces in URLs (as Larry Lustig pointed out it isn't necessarily a problem) - Then it isn't bad relational database design to have two columns that often have very similiar information.

The kind of repetition that is to be avoided (normalized) deals with repetition across multiple rows.  If you have two columns which are meant to contain different, but related information, then these two columns are perfectly OK and you aren't breaking any rules.  The fact that sometimes these two columns are equal (coincidentally) is not a problem.

You said:

> Possible solutions may err on the side of storing the group name
>   without spaces then using some regular expression to add the spaces
>   back. The focus of my question is how to eliminate the need for two
>   columns storing near-duplicate date.

From this I assume that what is most important to your system is the web group name.  If the group name were the driver then writing an expression that removes spaces would be trivial.  If the web group name *is* something that can be set arbitrarily based on the group name, then you should store the name with spaces and replace them with empty strings when you need a web group name.  If the web group name is not completely arbitrary then you really do have two independent data points and they *need* to be stored in two separate columns.